# Create a while loop that will check if the user selected the shape within 1.5 seconds

Tags: excel, vba

I work on a game that generate a random shape every 1.5 seconds and the user need to click on that shape before it disappear. Now, everything works fine so far. The game wait 1.5 seconds without blocking and generates a shape, but now I need to add a while loop that will check if the user clicked on that shape within the given time.

```vb
Sub Game()
    If i < 5 Then ' 5 Rounds, I'll change it in the future '
        CreateShape_Wait
        '  Implement here the loop, and check if the user clicked on the target shape '
        On Error GoTo NoShapeSelected
        If ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).Name = "targetShape" Then
            MsgBox ("test")
        End If
        On Error Resume Next
    End If
    
NoShapeSelected:
    ' Do nothing '
End Sub
```

```vb
Sub CreateShape_Wait()
    RandomShape
    Application.OnTime Now + 1.5 / 86400, "RemoveShape_Increment" ' Wait 1.5 Seconds (for the player to click on the shape) '
End Sub
```

How can I implement that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first thought is to let the shape itself run a code if you click it.
When creating the shape, use the `Shape.OnAction` property to make it "clickable" and call a subroutine.

Standard example: `Worksheets(1).Shapes(1).OnAction = "ShapeClick"`

One I have used before: `g1.OnAction = "modifyGroup"`
Where `g1` is a shape variable, and `modifyGroup` is a different sub.

In the called sub, you can either delete the shape, or set a boolean to be checked wheter it has been clicked or not. Depending on how you want to handle it.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know it exists